# Generate a list of length x: [0, .., x-1]

Tags: python

I'm sure python has a built in way to create an x size list where the contents are 0 through x-1, but I don't know how to do it. I've searched on Google as well as on here, I'm sure that I must've not been using the correct wording to find what I needed. Please help.

Ex: `len([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]) = 10`

Comment: `list(range(10))`

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for the [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) builtin:

```
range(x) # python 2
list(range(x)) # python 3
```